# How to filter city in Autocomple.intentBuilder

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
                .setCountry("IN")
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In setTypeFiler not filtering the it simply show CITIES

Answer (score 0):

use this and set setTypeFilder as per your need

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
       .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
       .setCountry("IN")
       .build();
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
       .setFilter(autocompleteFilter)
       .build(this)
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```